# How can I get the value of the ArrayList without returning size = 0?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

When I get the value of the arraylist, I get size = 0. I boot the ArrayList in Class Screen1, but I can not get the value of the Class Screen2 cont.

```
public class Variables {

public Variables() {
}

private int cont = 0;
private int correct = 0;


public int getCont(){
    return cont;
}
public void setCont(int cont){
    this.cont = cont;
}

public int getCorrect(){
    return correct;
}
public void setCorrect(int correct){
    this.correct = correct;
}}
```

Class Screen1

```
public class Screen1 extends ActionBarActivity {


Variables variables = new Variables();
ArrayList<Variables> variablesArrayList = new ArrayList<Variables>();
public int cont;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen1);


    variables.setCorrect(1);
    variables.setCont(1);
    variablesArrayList.add(variables);

}


public void sendTela1(View view){
    cont = variables.getCont();

    cont++;

    variablesArrayList.get(0).setCont(cont);

    }

}
```

Class Screen 2

This class I'm trying to get the value of ArrayList

```
public class Screen2 extends ActionBarActivity {

Variables variables = new Variables();
ArrayList<Variables> variablesArrayList = new ArrayList<Variables>();
int cont;
ImageView progressbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen2);


    progressbar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

    //this line, the arraylist is returning size = 0
    cont = variablesArrayList.get(1);


    switch (cont){
        case 1:
            progressbar.setImageResource(R.drawable.progressbar1);
            break;

        case 2:
            progressbar.setImageResource(R.drawable.progressbar2);
            break;
        case 3:
            progressbar.setImageResource(R.drawable.progressbar3);
            break;
        case 4:
            progressbar.setImageResource(R.drawable.progressbar4);
            break;
        case 5:
            progressbar.setImageResource(R.drawable.progressbar5);
            break;
    }}
```

Comment: Typo in public void setCorrect(int corret){ this.correct = correct; }

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a return size of 0 because in `screen2` activity you are creating a new list when you do: `ArrayList<Variables> variablesArrayList = new ArrayList<Variables>();`

To fix this, you need to pass the arraylist you created in `screen1` into `screen2`. You will have to implement [parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), but that will allow you to pass the data using `intents` and `bundles`.

Answer (score -1):

If you create a new object as you are doing in your screen2 with the line

```
ArrayList<Variables> variablesArrayList = new ArrayList<Variables>();
```

you will of course receive an empty arrayList. There are multiple ways of sending data from one Activity to another. **I suggest you look into bundles and using putExtras and later getExtras via Intents.** However, since you have a model class why not use that?

In your model class add

```
private static ArrayList<Variables> variablesArrayList;
```

Now add some setters and getters to update and retrieve your list

```
// getter
public static ArrayList<Variables> getList() {
   return variablesArrayList;
}

// setter
public static void setList(ArrayList<Variables> varArryList) {
   this.variablesArrayList = varArryList;
}
```

Now on screen1 set your arrayList and in screen2 (or 3, or 4, or 5, ect) retrieve it! Cheers!

Comment: Why the downvote? I am the only one who offered a solution outside of parcelable intents/bundles.